# Is the Fourier Transform injective?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of a probability distribuition is given by the Fourier transform of the distribuition, as follows: $$\phi(t)=\langle e^{itx} \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho\left(x\right) e^{itx} dx $$

But is this transformation injective? Can two different functions $\rho(x)$ have the same characteristic function?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: It is injective for the class of Schwartz functions, and the space of functions $L^2$.

Comment: There is even a formula for the  probability distribution in terms of the characteristic function, even without assuming that a density exists. See the book by K L Chung.